# prevent WHILE loop from retaining variables in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

First time asker, long time lurker. I am a new hobbyist with Python, so excuse my ignorance. I am trying to restart my script using a "while" loop. I restarts just fine, but I don't want the previously run code to retain any of the previous values.

What is happening here is that I enter two locations to get a distance (as in cartesian plane equation) and it references a database to determine some data. When the code goes through the while loop, it does not ask for a new location. I have a few different py files (modules might be the right word) that get referenced. The code is below. Excuse the mess:

```
#Mission Processor
from gridgrab import gridgrab
from Range import range
from table_f_reader import interpolate_elev, read_elev, bracketer
import sqlite3
import math

conn = sqlite3.connect ('chg_1L.db')
c = conn.cursor()
loop_back = 'y'
while loop_back == 'y':
    cht_range = int(round(range(), 0))
    print(cht_range, "meters")
    if cht_range % 100 == 0:
        elev = read_elev(cht_range)
    else:
        elev = interpolate_elev(cht_range)
    print('The range', cht_range, 'gives elevation', elev)
    loop_back = input('Do you want to run another mission? Enter Y or N:')
```

Here's the undesired output:

```
Battery Location: 1230
Target Location: 1233
Battery Grid: 12000 30000
Target Grid: 12000 33000
3000 meters
The range 3000 gives elevation 172.0
Do you want to run another mission? Enter Y or N:y
3000 meters
The range 3000 gives elevation 172.0
Do you want to run another mission? Enter Y or N:y
3000 meters
The range 3000 gives elevation 172.0
Do you want to run another mission? Enter Y or N:n
```

Thank you for reading all of this and your patience.

EDIT

Here's the other .py files the above code imports. The first is the distance calculator:

```
#MGRS Distance Calculator
import math
from gridgrab import gridgrab
from gridfix import gridfix
grids=gridgrab()
x1 = gridfix(int(grids[0]))
y1 = gridfix(int(grids[1]))
x2 = gridfix(int(grids[2]))
y2 = gridfix(int(grids[3]))
print('Battery Grid:', x1, y1)
print('Target Grid:', x2, y2)

def range():
    global x1, x2, y1, y2
    range = math.sqrt(((x2 - x1)**2) + ((y2 - y1)**2))
    return range
```

And here's a separate py file. It is essentially a database reader.
    import sqlite3
    import math
    from Range import range

```
def bracketer(x):     #function to bracket values
    global a, b
    a = math.floor(x/100)*100
    b = math.ceil(x/100)*100
    return a, b

def read_elev(range): #no interpolation required
    conn = sqlite3.connect ('chg_1L.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    entry_range = (range, )
    c.execute('SELECT range, elev FROM tableF WHERE range = ?', entry_range)
    row = c.fetchone()
    z, elev = row #z is throw away
    c.close()
    conn.close()
    return elev

def interpolate_elev(range):
    conn = sqlite3.connect ('chg_1L.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    bracketer(range) #bracket vaules and create tuple for database entry
    bracket = (a, b)
    c.execute('SELECT range, elev FROM tableF WHERE range = ? OR range = ?', bracket) #pull ranges and elevations from database.
    row = c.fetchall()
    lower = row[0] #pick out lower and upper data
    upper = row[1]
    lower_rg, lower_elv  = lower #unpack tuple
    upper_rg, upper_elv = upper
    inner_rg = range - lower_rg #interpolate
    outer_rg = upper_rg - lower_rg
    outer_elv = upper_elv - lower_elv
    x = inner_rg * outer_elv / outer_rg
    inner_elv = round(x, 1)
    elev = lower_elv + inner_elv
    c.close()
    conn.close()
    return elev
```

Comment: what does `range()` do? and what is the desired output?

Comment: And what is the output you *actually get*?

Comment: The output I actually get is above. 'range()' is the distance equation. It take two (x,y) grids I enter and determines the distance between them.

Comment: The desired output would be exactly like the first time it runs, only any time I enter "y", I want it to ask me for a new set of (x,y) coordinates.

Comment: You say it takes two things but it hasn't been passed anything. And you want to be asked for new coordinates but I don't see any code doing that. In fact I don't see anything inside the loop that would make different iterations have different output.

Comment: you should also name range() something else so that you don't overload the built in function [range()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

Comment: Alex Hall, the above edit has the other parts of the code that were stored in different py files and imported.

Comment: Albert Rothman, great point. Thanks.

Comment: @agugliemo, you can also use '@' in the comments to 'tag someone, this will notify them in their inbox so that can know that you have responded. You may want to take the site [tour] if you have not already done so.

Comment: You don't ever appear to change your x and y as they are set at the beginning of the second posted module and never update them late: `global x1, x2, y1, y2`. All the loop_back part does is restart the loop with the same data, why are you expecting different output on each iteration?

Comment: @AlbertRothman Thank you again for the tips. I think I have a misunderstanding of how and when modules run. I put the 'gridgrab()' function in the loop itself and it is working how I want it to. Thank you for your help.